# ASP Classic SQL connection strings quit overnight! Had to replace with something completely different, what happened?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I have a number of ASP classic webs running for 15+ years with the same connection strings.  One of the 2008 servers running SQL Server 2014 SP3 mysteriously rebooted last night and when it came back up, none of the webs would work. I kept getting an "invalid parameter in connection string" error message.

The connection string looks like:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=wmandc; User ID=myid; Password=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

I tried a number of different strings and finally found that worked:

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=localhost;Database=wmandc;Uid=myid;Pwd=xxxxx
```

I can't really find the reason for the reboot nor can I figure out why the connection strings no longer worked. There was no Windows Update last night.

While this was a test server, I'm afraid it will happen in production.

Does anyone have an idea what happened?

Comment: All the connection strings are kept in a single file.  The file date was over 4 years old. There are about 8 connection strings to different databases in it, all the same except for the catalog, and all had to be changed.  The old strings are the same that is running in production now... which is what is scaring me!

Comment: Add extra information to your question, not the comments.

Comment: Also, FYI, Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server has been deprecated for some time, and Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server should be used

Comment: Your websites and SQL servers run on a different machine? Did you uninstall SQL Server clients/drivers on webserver?

Comment: It seems the legacy SQLOLEDB driver (packaged with Windows) got corrupted but I can't say how/why. Note you should be able to specify Provider=`SQLNCLI11` instead of using ODBC (`Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}`) with ADO classic.

Comment: Dan:  Provider=SQLNCLI11 worked as well.  I will continue to use that.  Oddly enough, I have C# Windows services that are still using Provider=SQLOLEDB; and working so I''m even more confused...

Comment: Larnu: I was actually commenting on a post that has since been deleted.  Per Dan's comment, I assume that the Provider=SQLNCLI11 would be the best selection?

Comment: Salman: No,  nothing was uninstalled.  I this example all 8 databases are on the same computer and the webs all use the same code base on the same computer as well.